# Валовая улица, ударение

Tags: орфоэпия

На [Грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/moscow?alpha=%D0%92) предлагают произносить название с ударением на О, но, как правильно кто-то заметил, в этом случае кажется, что речь идёт о каких-то волах: Вол**о**вая как дополнительный вариант к слову "воловья".

Названа улица по [земляному валу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB_(%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0)), если я правильно понимаю. По-моему, от слова *"вал"* возникает прилагательное *"в**а**ловый",* а не *"вал**о**вый",* если речь не об экономике, где правильно *"валов**о**й".* В словарях даже нету слова на *-ый,* однако оно может понадобиться, если говоришь о чём-то, что находится на валу.

Вариантов, кстати, даже не два, а три: некоторые говорят "Валов**а**я".

Итак, вопрос: *как правильно ставить ударение (как у Грамоты или иначе) и почему именно так правильно?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Грамота.ру [дает](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/moscow?alpha=%D0%92) вариант ВалОвая улица** (как Артём уже заметил).

2) **Местные жители [тоже](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5:%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_(%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0)).**

> 21 июля 2013
>
> Правильно произносить ВалОвая улица. Только так! Я жила там в детстве и юности - все москвичи говорят именно так. Спасибо.
>
> Абсолютно верное замечание!!! ВалОвая улица. Я там тоже жила много лет назад. Москвичи всегда так говорили и говорят. А ударение в названии этой улицы как только не выворачивают сейчас. :) Елена

3) **Но у людей на слуху два варианта прилагательного** (не названия): валовОй и вАловый, причем они имеют значение "общий".

"В «Русском орфографическом словаре РАН» на правах варианта указана и форма вАловый. Таким образом, определяя, на какой слог падает ударение, необходимо учитывать, что оба варианта допустимы, но предпочтительной является форма валовОй".

4) **В толковом словаре дается одно прилагательное валовОй — общий,** в Нацкорпусе только один пример **на "вАловый**" (от слова ***вал***): Солиманъ въ ярости, что столь упорное ему дѣлаютъ сопротивленіе, (он) рѣшился **на валовый къ крѣпости приступъ.** [М. И. Веревкин (1782)]

Поэтому задача сложная, но **надо всё-таки ориентироваться на Справочник улиц.**

Comment: Спасибо, Арина! Хороший разносторонний ответ! Вы сама же говорите, что "валовОй" — общий и на него много примеров, а "вАловый" от "вала" и на него лишь один. Пускай один, но ведь нас действительно интересует случай, когда от "вала"! Разве не от него название должно быть в данном случае?

Comment: И ещё мне интересно: кого или что Вы цитируете в 3-м пункте?

Comment: В прилагательных с суффиксом ОВ  ударение регулярно смещается на суффикс или на окончание: сад - садовый, вишня - вишнёвый и вИшневый (устар.). Связь с исходным существительным  не исчезает, она просто ослабевает при переносе ударения, не подчеркивается. У глагола валить тоже ударение с вариантами. Также есть пословица: Вали валОМ - потом разберем. Поэтому меня не удивляет название "ВалОвая улица". А  Цитата из Интернета http://obrazovaka.ru/udarenie/v-slove-valovoy

Comment: Спасибо, Арина, за источник! Да, всё убедительно! Странно только, что вроде ВалОвая улица с таким ударением подразумевает прилагательное "валОвый", такое же, как у Вас "садовый" и "вишнёвый", но в словаре такого нету. Может, раньше было? И, может, и приступ тот к крепости тоже валОвый. Если нет, тогда всё равно не состыкуется всё как следует...

Answer (score 0):

По опыту передвижения по Садовому, в объявлениях маршрутов «Б» и «10» произошло изменение: Валов**а**я улица с середины 90-х гг. стала В**а**ловой (часть бывшего земляного вала).

Хотя устоявшейся акцентологической нормы для этого слова не найдено — в «Русском орфографическом словаре РАН» на правах варианта указана форма *в**а**ловый*, но предпочтительной является *валов**о**й*, — да и троллейбусная публика поменялась, но форма *Валов**а**я улица* более на слуху, возможно, по аналогии с *паровой*, *шаровой* и др.

Об «обосновании ответа» справочной службы: если допустить, что исходником для *вал**о**вая* (ж. р.) избирался не *валовой*, а ***валовий***, перешедший позже в свой смягчённый вариант, то это предположение объяснит такую заданность ударения на О.

По поводу упомянутых волов: у ***вала*** есть синоним *волна*.

Comment: Спасибо! Только откуда вариант с ударением на О всё-таки? Спасибо ещё за "земляной вал"! Вы написали с маленькой, и до меня дошло, что я странно решил, будто бы надо написать с большой.

Comment: Есть соображение.

Comment: Про волну, к сожалению, не понял.( А почему "валовИй" через И?

Comment: Меняете А на О и представляете волов? Логичнее ассоциировать с волной на том основании, что это синоним. Валовий — первичная форма, сохранившаяся только в украинском.

Comment: А-а, я подумал, что это украинский, но не был уверен совсем. Про волов это не я думаю, просто, когда раньше читал обсуждение ударения этого, кто-то сказал, что с "волами" было бы логичнее такое ударение. Но я не хотел сказать, что так же рассуждаю, и не хотел сказать, что наоборот. Я просто затруднялся разобраться правильно сам, понять, чем мотивироваться.